# calculate and draw of new plot by adding or multiplying a value to the previous plots values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, overleaf

I have created a plot by following latex code,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={X},
ylabel={Y}]
\addplot+[] table[row sep=crcr]{
1 1\\
2 2\\
3 3\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Now I want to add another plot that automatically draw something like the following

```
\addplot+[] table[row sep=crcr]{
1*a 1\\
2*a 2\\
3*a 3\\
};
```

How can I that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I do not think it is possible to refer to an other plot, but I do also not see how it can be needed - you can always separate the data from the plot like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\mya}{1.2}
\pgfplotstableread{
1 1
2 2
3 3
}\loadedtable
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={X},
ylabel={Y},
]
\addplot table {\loadedtable};
\addplot table[x expr={\mya*\thisrowno{1}}] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with two linear plots]