# Applying pgfplots.groupplots using an internal table code

Tags: pgfplots

I use the following code from the answer to [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283839/colour-each-x-co-ordinate-with-a-different-colour-in-a-bar-plot-in-pgfplot) to produce repeated plots.

Is it possible to include the table data inside the current tex document, and refer to them in the desired locations; instead of using the external csv data files?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, left=10mm, right=10mm, top=8mm, bottom=15mm}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\begin{document}

{
1

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=3 by 2, xticklabels at=edge bottom}, height=5cm, width=5cm, ybar=1pt, xtick=data, tick label style={font=\scriptsize}, x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
 symbolic x coords={metric1,metric2,metric3,metric4,metric5,metric6}, ylabel style={align=center}]
\nextgroupplot[title=a,ylabel={set1}, bar width=5pt]
\addplot[fill=blue!40]  table[x=metric,y=a1,col sep=space]  {colourData1.csv};
\addplot[fill=blue!80]  table[x=metric,y=a2,col sep=space]  {colourData1.csv};
\nextgroupplot[title=b,bar width=5pt]
\addplot[fill=blue!40]  table[x=metric,y=b1,col sep=space]  {colourData1.csv};
\addplot[fill=blue!80]  table[x=metric,y=b2,col sep=space]  {colourData1.csv};
\nextgroupplot[title=c,bar width=5pt]
\addplot[fill=blue!40]  table[x=metric,y=c1,col sep=space]  {colourData1.csv};
\addplot[fill=blue!80]  table[x=metric,y=c2,col sep=space]  {colourData1.csv};
\coordinate (mtop) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the first plot

\nextgroupplot[ylabel={set2}, bar width=5pt]
\addplot[fill=blue!40]  table[x=metric,y=a1,col sep=space]  {colourData2.csv};
\addplot[fill=blue!80]  table[x=metric,y=a2,col sep=space]  {colourData2.csv};
\nextgroupplot[bar width=5pt]
\addplot[fill=blue!40]  table[x=metric,y=b1,col sep=space]  {colourData2.csv};
\addplot[fill=blue!80]  table[x=metric,y=b2,col sep=space]  {colourData2.csv};
\nextgroupplot[bar width=5pt]
\addplot[fill=blue!40]  table[x=metric,y=c1,col sep=space]  {colourData2.csv};
\addplot[fill=blue!80]  table[x=metric,y=c2,col sep=space]  {colourData2.csv};
\coordinate (mbot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);% coordinate at bottom of the last plot
\end{groupplot}

\path (mtop-|current bounding box.west)-- node[anchor=south,rotate=90,yshift=-0.9cm] {\small Common} (mbot-|current bounding box.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

{
2

\pgfplotsset{select row/.style={x filter/.code={\ifnum\coordindex=#1\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi}},}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{yay-rainbow}{
{black!60!red,fill=white!00!red},
{black!60!red,fill=white!60!red},
{black!60!orange,fill=white!00!orange},
{black!60!orange,fill=white!60!orange},
{black!60!yellow,fill=white!00!yellow},
{black!60!yellow,fill=white!60!yellow},
{black!60!green ,fill=white!00!green },
{black!60!green ,fill=white!60!green },
{black!60!cyan  ,fill=white!00!cyan  },
{black!60!cyan  ,fill=white!60!cyan  },
{black!60!violet,fill=white!00!violet},
{black!60!violet,fill=white!60!violet}}

\def\twinplot#1#2{
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \row in {0,...,5}{
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \col in {1,...,2}{
  \edef\justplotit{
\noexpand\addplot+[bar shift=(\col-1.5)*\pgfplotbarwidth]
  table [x=metric, select row=\row, y=#1\col] {#2};}
  \justplotit}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}
[
group style={group size= 3 by 2,xticklabels at=edge bottom},
height=5cm,
width=5cm,
ybar=1pt,
tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
symbolic x coords={metric1,metric2,metric3,metric4,metric5,metric6},
ylabel style={align=center},
cycle list name=yay-rainbow,
max space between ticks=15,
]

\pgfkeys{/pgf/bar width=5pt}
\nextgroupplot [title=a, ylabel=set1] \twinplot{a}{colourData1.csv}
\nextgroupplot [title=b,] \twinplot{b}{colourData1.csv}
\nextgroupplot [title=c,] \twinplot{c}{colourData1.csv}
\coordinate (mtop) at (rel axis cs:0,1);

\nextgroupplot [ ylabel=set1] \twinplot{a}{colourData2.csv}
\nextgroupplot [] \twinplot{b}{colourData2.csv}
\nextgroupplot [] \twinplot{c}{colourData2.csv}
\coordinate (mbot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
\end{groupplot}

\path (mtop-|current bounding box.west) --
  node [anchor=south, rotate=90, yshift=-0.9cm] {\small Common}
  (mbot-|current bounding box.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
%the data in the csv files are as follows
\begin{verbatim}
metric  a1  a2  b1  b2  c1  c2
metric1 30  60  50  100 50  100
metric2 40  80  60  120 25  50
metric3 50  100 80  160 60  120
metric4 60  120 60  120 89  178
metric5 70  140 25  50  20  40
metric6 80  160 30  60  23  46
\end{verbatim}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `pgfplotstableread` like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669541/8650

Comment: @– hpekristiansen Thank you for your comment. Your solution works fine with the first picture, but it gave an error for the second picture as in the following message
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Emsb.png

Comment: You need to edit your code to be a *Minimal* (non-)Working Example. You can not expect people to enter data from a picture.

Comment: @–hpekristiansen I am sorry. I edited my post, and included the data in the csv files at the end. both colourData1.csv and colourData2.csv files include the same data.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{yay-rainbow}{
{black!60!red, fill=white!00!red},
{black!60!red, fill=white!60!red},
{black!60!orange, fill=white!00!orange},
{black!60!orange, fill=white!60!orange},
{black!60!yellow, fill=white!00!yellow},
{black!60!yellow, fill=white!60!yellow},
{black!60!green ,fill=white!00!green},
{black!60!green ,fill=white!60!green},
{black!60!cyan  ,fill=white!00!cyan},
{black!60!cyan  ,fill=white!60!cyan},
{black!60!violet, fill=white!00!violet},
{black!60!violet, fill=white!60!violet},
}

\pgfplotsset{select row/.style={x filter/.code={\ifnum\coordindex=#1\else\def\pgfmathresult{}\fi}},}

\def\twinplot#1#2{
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \row in {0,...,5}{
\addplot+[bar shift=(1-1.5)*\pgfplotbarwidth] table [x=metric, select row=\row, y=#11] {#2};
\addplot+[bar shift=(2-1.5)*\pgfplotbarwidth] table [x=metric, select row=\row, y=#12] {#2};
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
metric  a1  a2  b1  b2  c1  c2
metric1 30  60  50  100 50  100
metric2 40  80  60  120 25  50
metric3 50  100 80  160 60  120
metric4 60  120 60  120 89  178
metric5 70  140 25  50  20  40
metric6 80  160 30  60  23  46
}\colourData
\begin{groupplot}[
group style={group size= 3 by 2,
xticklabels at=edge bottom},
height=5cm,
width=5cm,
ybar=1pt,
tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
symbolic x coords={metric1, metric2, metric3, metric4, metric5, metric6},
ylabel style={align=center},
cycle list name=yay-rainbow,
max space between ticks=15,
/pgf/bar width=5pt,
]

\nextgroupplot[title=a, ylabel=set1] \twinplot{a}{\colourData}
\nextgroupplot[title=b,] \twinplot{b}{\colourData}
\nextgroupplot[title=c,] \twinplot{c}{\colourData}

\nextgroupplot[ylabel=set1] \twinplot{a}{\colourData}
\nextgroupplot[] \twinplot{b}{\colourData}
\nextgroupplot[] \twinplot{c}{\colourData}
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Six colored bar graphs in a grid]